# Set current, prev, next in array after ajax post

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have this PHP array corresponding to messages that show when clicked 'next'.

```
Array ( [1] => 1 [4] => 4 [5] => 5 [7] => 7 [13] => 13 )
```

First, #1 shows, where #4 is retrieved through an Ajax POST (the click 'next'). That works, as you can see here:

```
if(isset($_POST['mssID'])) { $current_message = $_POST['nextKey']; }
// the message with that ID shows
```

Then, the problem is that I can't set the current key (#4) in the same array after the post.
Next problem is that I can't set prev() and next() in the array.

Anyone know how to set the right current(), prev() and next()?

---

Expected output when $current_message == 4:

```
<div>message #4</div>
<a href="1">prev</a> | <a href="5">next</a>
```

Comment: I'm really not sure what you want here.

Comment: The array stays the same. But I want #4 to be the current key, so I can set #1 as prev() and #5 as next.

Comment: Post your expected output

Comment: How is the array created?

Comment: I add elements to the array using array_push. That is why the array isn't indexed properly. Hence the 1, 4, 5, 7, 13.

Comment: Trying to work on a solution. Will update you.

Comment: @KJS
Have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like,

```
$array = array( 1 => 1, 4 => 4, 5 => 5, 7 => 7, 13 => 13 ) ;
// your initial array

$current_message = 4;
// current is 4

$keys = array_keys($array);
// make array indexed from 0    

$search = array_search($current_message , $keys);
// search inside indexed array the key

$prev = $next = 0; // initailize to 0

if($current_message != reset($array)) // check if current is not first
    $prev = $keys[$search-1];

if($current_message != end($array)) // check if current is not last
    $next = $keys[$search+1];

var_dump($prev,$next);
```

Will give you

```
int(1)
int(5)
```

But, it will be one less line, if you make the array indexed while filling it.

Comment: Thanks @Viral! This one nailed it right away. Hope it will be helpful to others as well. It fixed my problem by just implementing your code. Very easy!

Answer (score 3):

Well here's my solution, I've made functions for prev and next.

```
<?php
$array = array("1" => "11", "7" => "22", "3" => "33");
function gen_next($array,$currentValue)
{
    //get array key from the value
    $array_key_from_value = array_search($currentValue, $array);
    $string_of_keys = implode('|', array_keys($array));
    $array_of_keys = explode('|', $string_of_keys);
    for($i=0;$i<count($array_of_keys);$i++)
    {
        if($array_key_from_value == $array_of_keys[$i])
        {
            if($i == (count($array_of_keys)-1))
            {
                return "No next value";//the current index is the last of the array, can't set a next
            }
            else
            {
                return $array_of_keys[$i+1];//else return the next index
            }
        }
    }
}
function gen_prev($array,$currentValue)
{
    //get array key from the value
    $array_key_from_value = array_search($currentValue, $array);
    $string_of_keys = implode('|', array_keys($array));
    $array_of_keys = explode('|', $string_of_keys);
    for($i=0;$i<count($array_of_keys);$i++)
    {
        if($array_key_from_value == $array_of_keys[$i])
        {
            if($i == 0)
            {
                return "No prev value";//the current index is the last of the array, can't set a next
            }
            else
            {
                return $array_of_keys[$i-1];//else return the next index
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

**Usage**

```
var_dump(gen_next($array, '33'));
var_dump(gen_prev($array, '22'));
string 'No next value' (length=13)
string '1' (length=1)
```

Comment: Thank you so much Akshay! I can use this code in many other situations. The answer Viral gave was just perfect for this particular situation. Yours will be used elsewhere! Thanks again!

Comment: @KJS
Glad it helped you, took me quite sometime to figure it out ;)

Comment: Very educational as well. Learning a lot from you guys! :-)